# Python and FastCGI protocol

Tags: python, cgi, wsgi, fastcgi

I try to understand what types of web-servers exist (static Apache Server, Apache Server + CGI, Apache Server + FastCGI).

So, my question: how to setup Apache Server to run python with FastCGI protocol? Or python requires only WSGI protocol?

Comment: What do you mean by *"is it real"*? As opposed to imaginary? Or do you mean *"possible"*, or *"sensible"* or something else? Thank you.